# Mapview lat lon co-ordinates - incompatible types in assignment

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, android-mapview

I have lat lon coordinates stored in a database table and I want to have them displayed in a mapview like this:

```
region.center.latitude = place.lat;
region.center.longitude = place.lon;
```

the lat and lon are stored as doubles in the table. this is the error I'm getting:

```
**error: incompatible types in assignment**
```

I hope that's enough info to go on. I think I'm getting the error because they are doubles and I'm using the wrong syntax to display them.

thanks so much for any help

Comment: by the way, if I make an NSLog like: NSLog(@"lat %@", place.lat); I get the correct lat info outputted to the console.

Answer (score 0):

This was how I solved the problem:

```
region.center.latitude = [place.lat floatValue];
region.center.longitude = [place.lon floatValue];
```